# derivative filter for computing speed from robot rangefinder

Tags: filters, python, derivative

I have a laser rangefinder on my robot and I need to compute the speed of the detected object. I have seen many different filters for that, but all of them apply only to offline data, or introduce delay as they rely on past and future points, like (Xn+1 - Xn-1)/2Tn.

I am using this signal for controlling the position of a drone so no delay is allowed. When I researched, the type of filter that I need is described as:

- Online
- Backward-looking
- Causal

But I never found an actual implementation of such a filter.

I guess a Kalman filter would fit, but that's a big beast and I am not familiar with its math, so if something simpler existed I would be happy.

How do I implement such a filter ? Is there one such filter already implemented in a library, in any language (but preferably Python) ?

Comment: For up to 3rd order filters see: [How one can perform a noise free first order derivation in discrete domain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28811/how-one-can-perform-a-noise-free-first-order-derivation-in-discrete-domain/42133)

Comment: Here is a literature reference I have not fully digested but which may have what you are after: Hugh L. Kennedy: "Multidimensional Digital Smoothing Filters for Target Detection", Signal Processing, Volume 114, September 2015, Pages 251-264, [arXiv:1410.0582](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0582).

Comment: Hugh L. Kennedy gives more references in an answer to a [question in ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_a_digital_lowpass_differentiator_filter_Is_it_obtained_by_cascading_of_highpass_and_lowpass_filters).